# In visual studio find reference is not working(line numbers showing zero)

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

In visual studio, I am trying to find all references. But it shows only zeros. Basically, it shows all related scripts with line numbers which the search word exists.

[image]

So can any please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you trying to search them? Try click once on the according class/field/method etc and press `ALT`+`SHIFT`+`F12`

Comment: Also are this your script files or is this maybe part of a dll?

Comment: Thank you for your response @derHugo
1. I am using a mac. COMMAND + SHIFT + R.
2. Those are my script files. (I am doing project unity with the visual studio editor )